# UICollectionView app crashes with UICollectionViewCell not key value compliant

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I started creating a project with UICollectionView.  I dragged a UICollectionViewController to storyboard and made properly identified it in the inspector.  Then I dragged in a UITableViewCell and a UILabel into it.  I created MyCell with a UILabel property and connected it to the outlet.  The cell is properly identified in the inspector as well.

But when I run the app it crashed with the:

[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cellLabel

where cellLabel is the UILabel property of MyCell.  Here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
    return cell;
}
```

And Cell is the identifier in the Attributes Inspector.

What could be wrong?

Comment: `cell.cellLabel.text` check here

Comment: dont you have to check if cell is nil and create a new instance in that case?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya what do you mean? calvinBhai this is the boilerplate code provided, there is no check for nil in any of the sample codes ive reviewed so far.

Answer (score 1):

Check in Interface-Builder if you set the CustomClass property for you custom Cell to `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It was an XCode5 error.  It didnt associate the target membership for the MyCell.m class file for some reason.